# wkhtmltopdf: how to use it?

Tags: php, pdf, wkhtmltopdf

I want to be able to generate and save a PDF version of a PHP page. I found out, on Stackoverflow, that the most recommended is wkhtmltopdf: http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/

However, I don't have any Shell or binary knowledge; I only know HTML and PHP.

Could anyone CLEARLY guide me on how to get a php page generate a PDF document using wkhtmltopdf (using only FTP and PHP)?

Comment: Have the answers worked for you?

Answer (score 3):

Did you read wiki section of the project homepage? It has [IntegrationWithPhp](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/wiki/IntegrationWithPhp) page. Hope that thelps.

Read comments to see how to use the class thats found in the wiki:

```
$html = file_get_contents("http://www.google.com");
//echo $html;
$pdf = new WKPDF();
$pdf->set_html($html);
$pdf->render();
$pdf->output(WKPDF::$PDF_EMBEDDED,'sample.pdf');
```

Comment: seems to be 404 (R.I.P.)

Comment: Found copy of the page from 12-23-2011 here: http://web.archive.org/web/20121029220125/http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/wiki/IntegrationWithPhp